# Get the value of input tag for Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">
<ul></ul>
  <script>
    var value;
    var wikiapi;
    $('#autocomplete').on('keypress',function(e){
        if(e.which==13){
            value=$(this).val();
            wikiapi="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=iwlinks&iwprop=url&titles="+value+"&format=json";
            $.ajax({
                url:wikiapi,
                crossDomain:true,
                dataType:"jsonp",
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                    },
                success: function(data){
                        var links=data.query.pages[171166].iwlinks;
                        var title=data.query.pages[171166].title;
                        $.each(links,function(i,val){
                        $('ul').append('<li><a href='+val.url+'>'+title +'</a></li>');
                    });
                console.log(data.query.pages[171166].iwlinks[0].url);
                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Hi, I am trying to retrieve the value from input tag. But It seems the method I've tried is not working. The value is not passed to the wikiapi var at all. Hence the ajax request cannot proceed. Can anyone point out the problem please.
I've also tried "..$('#autocomplete').on('click',function(){
........} also but not working.

Comment: value is undefined in your case, you have declared and used it as part of the url

Comment: Is it reaching the success?

Comment: Where do you get the value for `value` which brings us back to question, you started asking something and ended up asking something else.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous, `value` and `wikiap` variables will be undefined

Comment: Please post the HTML code for the `input`.

Comment: @karthikGanesan now completed but issue is same

Comment: @funcoding Thats the problem value is not reaching till wikiapi and this not till ajax

Comment: Add this to your ajax: `error: console.log` and let me know what error is shown.

Comment: At first I hope you are pressing the return key after your input? e.which==13 means the ENTER key, second your are requesting an jsonp call against a json api `&format=json`

Comment: @Andrële ajax call is not a problem dude. That part is already working with hardcoded title outside of keypress function

Comment: seems it is working for me https://jsfiddle.net/zsrde00v/1/ for value "test" check your page[] value that you are providing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick check inside the success function as to what `data` was storing. After just a couple of examples I noticed the key (the six digits) were different for each example. Therefore, `var links=data.query.pages[171166].iwlinks;` and `var title=data.query.pages[171166].title;` will only work for test. In order to get the keys of `data.query.pages` you need a `for loop`. I've also added `$('ul').empty()` to empty out whatever was in the list. Here's the code needed to get it to work:

```js
var value;
var wikiapi;
$('#autocomplete').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    value = $(this).val();
    wikiapi = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=iwlinks&iwprop=url&titles=" + value + "&format=json";
    $.ajax({
      url: wikiapi,
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('ul').empty();
        for (var key in data.query.pages) {
          if (data.query.pages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var links = data.query.pages[key].iwlinks;
            var title = data.query.pages[key].title;
          }
        }
        $.each(links, function(i, val) {
          $('ul').append('<li><a href=' + val.url + '>' + title + '</a></li>');
        });
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">
<ul>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I paste your code to jsfiddle with this success function `success: function(data){ console.log(data) }` the ajax call works fine.

So you have an Problem to handle your result from the API.

I have rewritten your code to make it more readable:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#autocomplete', function (e) {

    if (e.which === 13) {

        var options = {
            url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", 
            data: {
                action: "query",
                prop: "iwlinks",
                iwprop: "url",
                titles: $(this).val(),
                format: "json"
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        };

        $.ajax( options ).done(function (data) {

            var html ='';

            $.each(data.query.pages, function(pageKey, pageValue) {

                $.each(pageValue.iwlinks, function(linkKey, linkValue) {
                    html += '<li><a href="' + linkValue.url + '">' + pageValue.title + '</a></li>';
                });

            });

            $('ul').html(html);

        }).fail(function (err) {

            console.log(err);
            alert('Ooops');

        });
    }

});
```

I have extracted the ajax options and added the GET parameter from the URL to them. I also iterate over result pages and the link object to generate the listitems.

Here can you read about the jQuery ajax method and the options: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/